# Move apps from Test environment to Prod

Tags: sharepoint-online, deployment, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am new to the Power Apps, and I need some advice to see the best way to move the apps from test to prod environment is?

Answer (score 0):

Best and recommended way to move multiple apps/flows from one environment to another environment is using **Solutions**:

Check below documentation for more information about Solutions: [Solutions Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview)

---

**Additional**:

If you just want to move single app quickly from one environment to another, you can export it from first environment & import it in another environment.

[Export and import canvas app packages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/export-import-app)

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.